# What is the fastest way to guess a word that someone is thinking by asking yes/no questions?

Tags: probability, game-theory, information-theory

For example, let's say I'm thinking of the word "sponge." A friend has to figure out what the word is through a series of yes or no questions. He can ask if the word is edible, to which I would say "No" (which is what most people would say, which is hard to formalize). Obviously, my friend can ask if the word is "potato", but if information theory has taught us anything it is that those kind of questions are the worst in terms of the information they give. I can't really formalize what I mean by a "word" (the string "abc" isn't a word, after all) other than that it has to be something that has a clear definition if you search it up on Google. What I'm asking for is a way to make something like this more "binary searchable" to figure out the word with as few questions as possible. If anyone can provide some general insight to this problem that'd be great.

Comment: I think the best strategy is to consideer the list of all "words" (whatever that means) sorted alphabetically and numbered. Then, guessing the word is equivalent to guess the number. This can be done with $\log_2(n)$ questions. If we assume , say $10$ million words , we would need just $24$ questions.

Comment: Binary search through a dictionary seems like a good strategy.

Comment: Add "prior probability" to your research for the method to solve it.

Answer (score 4):

Take a dictionary. Open it in the middle, see what's the first word on that page and ask “In the dictionary, does that word appear before […]?” Then you will know in which half of the dictionary that word is. Then see what's the word which is in the middle of that region and as k the similar question concerning that word. And so on.

Comment: Doesn't this approach assume that every word is guessed with equal probability?

Comment: @toliveira I don't see why.

Comment: Imagine that, for some reason, all the words that people guess are on the second half of the dictionary. The first time you ask is useless.

Comment: @toliveira If I saw any reason for supposing that that happens, my answer would have been different.

Comment: @toliveira In that case you weigh each word with its probability of being chosen, before you pick the middle of the dictionary. Exact same approach applies. But I still see no hint that that's something the OP even wants to consider.

Comment: @toliveira Actually, this rather assumes that (or is optimized towards the case that) each word is picked with probability proportional to the sapce it occupies in the dictionary. It is not uncommon for particularly basic words to have more lengthy entries. E.g., in my OALDCE, "be" occupies half a page, whereas "venison" has a one-liner. (I wanted to use "defenestration"  as an example -- why does English have a single word for the rare(?) act of throwing someone out of the window, but needs a bunch of words for a common concept such as "the day after tomorrow"? -- but it is not in my issue)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen That depends slightly on how you define "middle". That being said, I have yet to see a dictionary that actually numbers its entries the way most printed media numbers pages. So it would take some work to find the middle by entries, especially if you're going to repeat it 15-20 times.